# Shuffle Controls work with Android?

Tags: headphones, media-button

I've used an iPod Shuffle for the past year and have come to appreciate the control "pod" on the headphones. [Here's a link](http://www.sonystyle.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10551&storeId=10151&langId=-1&productId=8198552921666001159) to the Sony buds I use. The controls up by the ear work very well on long bike rides or even when lifting at the gym. Don't have to pull the player out of my jersey or shorts pocket to change volume or skip to next song.

Now that I'm using my Android phone for music, I'm wondering if anyone has spotted any little hacks or apps that would enable iPod Shuffle headphones to work with an Android?

Comment: So you've tried it and it didn't work?  I use the music controls on my Motorola S9 bluetooth headphones on my Droid as well as on other devices.  I know the bluetooth stack that controls playback controls is standard, it seems odd to me that the wired headphones would only work with iProducts.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. No love. Since the headphones are sold specifically for Shuffle I won't be too surprised if they're not standard. But would be cool if some enterprising person figured out a way to get 'em to work :-)

Comment: That would be cool. Sorry I didn't have an answer, but you could always sell your ipod lovin earbuds on ebay and buy an Android friendly pair.

Comment: maybe I should start a new topic for this... but do you have a link to an android friendly pair that isn't bluetooth?

Comment: +1 @Matt for selling the ipod earbuds :) @Chris_K it looks like, at least currently, in order to have all the controls like volume, skip, pause/play, they have to be bluetooth. I haven't found any that do all that from the 3.5mm jack. The ones for the vibrant are "supposed" to answer call, pause/play & skip song, but the only thing I can get mine to do is play/pause.

Comment: Many earphones come with these controls near the V-split of the cables or elsewhere. I even have two pair that came with, respectively, my ADP1 and my Nexus One. Obviously they work. I guess yours really only were designed for Apple.

Comment: I have something that will help you control your phone with headphone buttons, but I am not sure it will work with your shuffle headphones. There is an app called Headset Button Controller on the market, and there is a trial version to try out first. You can set it to take commands from headphone buttons (for example, my headset has one button and I can set it to pause/play if i press it once, go to next song if i press the button twice quickly, etc) it is worth a try

Answer (score 2):

Apps like [Headset Button Controller](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headset) are the most likely to do what you ask. That said the headphones you use have to be hardware compatible with the Android device you are using.

My Sennheiser  MM50's are designed for iPhone but work on my Google Nexus S and HTC Incredible S, so I'd expect the same to be true of other iPhone compatible headphones and Android devices.

That said, the MM50's do exhibit different behaviour on either phone (e.g. press on Nexus mutes the call as I'd like, but on Incredible it ends the call - Grrr).

Answer (score -1):

Jays Headset control. Works perfdectly on my HTC Desire HD with House of Marley Exodus headset which controls are made for iphone-ipod - playing default music player, Poweramp, 3, DS Audio, Youtube, Tune In Radio, Jazz Radio, etc, etc. Wonderful! I have read in the review it also works perfectly on HTC One X, HTC Incredible S, HTC Sensation, SGS2, Sony Experia S.